# Trying to mock a module that I'm importing in most of my components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I have a React project. In this project we are using some SDK to handle authentication-related activities. This SDK is imported in almost all the components. This SDK has other internal dependencies.

```
import { exampleSDK } from "../../path/exampleSDK";

const exampleComponent = () => {
   const { onAuthenticate, onLogout } = exampleSDK({}) // just few examples

   return (<><div>Example Component</div>/</>)
}
```

This `exampleSDK` has internal dependencies which seem to be failing when I'm trying to call the components in my unit tests. I don't have to write the unit test for the SDK. I want to be able to mock the implementation of the `exampleSDK` while testing the components. currently, I'm getting the following error when I'm calling the component with `render()` function from `"@testing-library/react"`.

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'y')

> 12 | ExampleHandler.prototype = Object.create(window.x.y.prototype)
                                                         ^
```

This is implemented in a module which is being called inside the `exampleSDK`.

I tried using the `Object.defineProperty(window, 'x', {y: {}})` but that didn't work(maybe I'm doing it wrong).

Is there a way to skip the error part or if it is possible to mock the implementation of the SDK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to mock your SDK you can do so by `jest.mock()`. Try this out in your test

```
jest.mock('../../path/exampleSDK', () => ({
  exampleSDK: (args) => {
    // Return some values such as:
    return {
      onAuthenticate: jest.fn(),
      onLogout: jest.fn()
    };
  }
}));

test('your test description', () => {
  // Write your test here
})
```

There are more than 1 way to mock. Above is just one of them.

You can check out `jest.spyOn()` or `.mockImplementation()` or `.mockReturnValue()`

Search for these things on the jest docs - https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-function-api